# Black text color for ios statusbar phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to change text color of ios statusbar in my phonegap app but it's not working for me.
I tried different combinations of settings for cordova.statusbar plugin and core settings.
Now I have this in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

Which settings should I use to get black color of text in my app's statusbar?

P.S. so sorry for my English

Comment: default is black text on white status bar, did you install the plugin?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes I have `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" />` in my config. I also tried to put this code `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" /><preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />` before and after installed plugins...

Comment: Are you using cordova or phonegap build?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes and I see org.apache.cordova.statusbar in the list of installed plugins in the phonegap build

Comment: Yes? I'm asking if you are using cordova OR phonegap build, the answer can't be yes, has to be "I use cordova" OR "I use phonegap build"

Comment: If you are using phonegap build, put this line on the config.xml and remove the other you are using `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the first one, that doesn't exist
And change the `StatusBarStyle` to `lightcontent`

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Comment: I've removed the first line and now my code `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" /><preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />` , but color of my status bar still be white :(

Comment: and which color do you want? you just said you wanted white text

Comment: Did you install the plugin on first place? default will make the text black

Answer (score 2):

```
StatusBar.styleDefault();
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/

I am using framework 7. I need to call the above command to set text to black. I am NOT setting style in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `styleLightContent()` for white text, if your status bar is black and `styleDefault()` for black text if your background is white.

The doc comments for this mehtods:

```js
// Use the default statusbar (dark text, for light backgrounds).
statusBar.styleDefault();

// Use the lightContent statusbar (light text, for dark backgrounds).
statusBar.styleLightContent();
```

On Android the `preference` in `config.xml` has no effect. You have to call the methods on runtime. [See docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#android-quirks)

Unfortunately it does not set the status bar text automatically.
You have to find out the theme color of the status back to decide which method you call. Or use your own fixed theme or overlay it.